# How to create 3 div with portrait images in a row responsive with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

This maybe easy but it feels more tricky for me to display 3 images in a row with responsive layout by using bootstrap

I want to create a page in my website with something like this -
[image: 3 images in a row]

Here's what I want to achieve in my website's gallery page
https://www.avivabaig.com/portraits

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create your example site structure using bootstrap, visit this site for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

```css
.image-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.image-box {
    max-height: 235px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head><body><div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="image-box">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1352&amp;q=80" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="image-box">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452827073306-6e6e661baf57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=967&amp;q=80" alt="">
            </div>
        </div><div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="image-box">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1352&amp;q=80" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        
        
    </div>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My sketch of it, using the scripts and stylesheets for Bootstrap 4.0.0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Three images</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.col-sm-4 img{width:100%;border:2px solid #fff;outline:2px solid #000}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a32108_078200849e0545229d2016399b977003~mv2.jpeg/v1/fill/w_433,h_613,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-01-14%20at%2012_00_53%20PM.webp"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a32108_fb68b3206eea49008cf9b17fd8382041~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_433,h_613,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/IMG-4811.webp"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a32108_01c000ce3450418ea4fcc20e3ed38a45~mv2.jpeg/v1/fill/w_433,h_613,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-01-14%20at%2012_00_53%20PM.webp"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above the complete file to copy/paste, below the snippet to run and test:

```css
.col-sm-4 img{width:100%;border:2px solid #fff;outline:2px solid #000}
.col-sm-4 img{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px}/* just to make the snippet clearer */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a32108_078200849e0545229d2016399b977003~mv2.jpeg/v1/fill/w_433,h_613,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-01-14%20at%2012_00_53%20PM.webp"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a32108_fb68b3206eea49008cf9b17fd8382041~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_433,h_613,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/IMG-4811.webp"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/a32108_01c000ce3450418ea4fcc20e3ed38a45~mv2.jpeg/v1/fill/w_433,h_613,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/WhatsApp%20Image%202021-01-14%20at%2012_00_53%20PM.webp"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Check the options for the syntax, since you may even prefer to use a `col-xs-4` class rather than `col-sm-4` or other.